# shell - cat - merge files content into one big file

Tags: shell, cat

I'm trying, using bash, to merge the content of a list of files (more than 1K) into a big file.

I've tried the following cat command:

```
cat * >> bigfile.txt
```

however what this command does is merge everything, included also the things already merged.

e.g.
file1.txt

```
content1
```

file2.txt

```
content2
```

file3.txt

```
content3
```

file4.txt

```
content4
```

bigfile.txt

```
content1
content2
content3
content2
content3
content4
content2
```

but I would like just

```
content1
content2
content3
content4
```

inside the .txt file

The other way would be `cat file1.txt file2.txt ...` and so on... but I cannot do it for more than 1k files!

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that you put `bigfile` in the same directory, hence making it part of `*`. So something like

```
cat dir/* > bigfile
```

should just work as you want it, with your `fileN.txt` files located in `dir/`

Comment: ... or `cat * >/tmp/bigfile; mv /tmp/bigfile .`.

Comment: I think fabioln is intentionally including `bigfile.txt` in the input; he wants to add to the file from the various `file*.txt`, but eliminating duplicates at the same time.

Comment: Thank you guys. Yes, that was the problem! I put the bigfile in the same dir... so I used the command you gave me (cat dir/* > bigfile)! Just another question: why you put just > instead of >> is it the same? Thank you!

Comment: @fabioln79 using `>>` you append the output to the file, using `>` you overwrite the entire contents.

Comment: Can one always rely on the "star notation" to merge the files in the right order?

Comment: Depends on what your "right" order is; the shell will expand `*` in alphabetically sorted order, see https://serverfault.com/a/122743

Answer (score 4):

On re-reading your question, it appears that you want to append data to `bigfile.txt`, but
without adding duplicates. You'll have to pass everything through `sort -u` to filter out duplicates:

```
sort -u * -o bigfile.txt
```

The `-o` option to sort allows you to safely include the contents of `bigfile.txt` in the input to sort before the file is overwritten with the output.

EDIT: Assuming bigfile.txt is sorted, you can try a two-stage process:

```
sort -u file*.txt | sort -um - bigfile.txt -o bigfile.txt
```

First we sort the input files, removing duplicates. We pipe that output to another `sort -u` process, this one using the `-m` option as well which tells `sort` to merge two previously sorted files. The two files we will merge are `-` (standard input, the stream coming from the first `sort`), and `bigfile.txt` itself. We again use the `-o` option to allow us to write the output back to `bigfile.txt` after we've read it as input.

Comment: I've amended the answer to allow new data to be merged into `bigfile.txt` in such a way that it stays sorted with no duplicates introduced. I think this is the best you can do without switching to a more structured format (such as a database).

Answer (score 4):

You can keep the output file in the same directory, you just have to be a bit more sophisticated than `*`:

```
shopt -s extglob
cat !(bigfile.txt) > bigfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a question related to this command: the directory containing the file has a size of 557GB however the bigfile created has a size of 495. I don't know how to explain this. I'm doing something wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @fabioln79 With amount of info provided, suspect this might be due to the space actually used vs. Block size (Read up on the latter)

Answer (score 2):

> The other way would be cat file1.txt file2.txt ... and so on... but I cannot do it for more than 1k files!

This is what xargs is for:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "file*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 cat > bigfile.txt
```

Comment: does xargs execute the command for *each* argument?  If so, should you use '>>' instead of '>'?  I'm thinking that when it's done, bigfile.txt will only contain the contents of the last file passed to it.

Comment: xargs runs the command once for all arguments, you don't need to use `'>>'`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  The man page wasn't very clear to me on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but still I'll give another approach with `xargs`

1. list the files you want to concat

   > ls | grep [pattern] > filelist
2. Review your files are in the proper order with `vi` or `cat`. If you use a suffix (1, 2, 3, ..., N) this should be no problem
3. Create the final file

   > cat filelist | xargs cat >> [final file]
4. Remove the filelist

   > rm -f filelist

Hope this helps anyone

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
cat `ls -1 *` >> bigfile.txt
```

I don't have a unix machine handy at the moment to test it for you first.

Comment: -1 This doesn't solve anything, and introduces some new problems of its own.  Don't use `ls` when the wildcard already expands to the files you want!  Don't use unquoted file names (the output from the backticks) because it breaks if file names contain whitespace.

Comment: I was actually thinking of a loop when I wrote that, but it didn't come out of my head properly.  I like Barton's answer better anyway.